# reemplazar en un string valores entre simbolos

Tags: javascript, string, regex

tengo el siguiente string:

```
Var text='¡Hola $var1$! Gracias $var2$'
```

Cómo puedo reemplazar lo que está entre $ por el valor de la variable.
Ejemplo:

```
var1="Juan", var2="Pedro"

Resultado='¡Hola Juan! Gracias Pedro'
```

El texto puede tener mas variables y contenido, por lo cual no puedo hacer con indexOf

Intente con exp. regulares, pero no las se usar muy bien.

```
var exp = text.search(/'$'[a-z A-Z]'$'/i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que podemos hacer es convertir tu texto en el sistema de Plantillas de literales de Javascript.

Primero usamos un [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) para poner el formato adecuado.

la regex -> `/\$(\w+)\$/g` busca aquella parte del texto que sea `"$"` seguido de texto y seguido de `"$"`

Donde:

- `\$` es el caracter `"$"`
- `(\w+)` es el grupo a capturar, el texto entre los `"$"`
- `/g` la bandera global para buscar en todo el texto

asi que `"$var1$"` pasaría a ser `"${var1}"`

Despues se evalua el string para que lo interprete como una plantilla

```js
var myString = `¡Hola $var1$! Gracias $var2$`;

var1 = "User1";

var2 = "User2";

myString = myString.replace(/\$(\w+)\$/g, "${$1}");

console.log(eval('`'+myString+'`'));
```

Comment: Me haz ganado por segundos, +1

Comment: no puedo, por que recibo ese string por get, por lo cual no puedo modificar, tengo que reemplazar lo que esta entre $$ por el valor

Comment: @AlexisGranja ah, entonces no quieres usar plantillas de JS si no tu propio formato... para eso has de usar Regex.

Comment: si, asi mismo, una expresion regular necesito pero no logro hacerla

Comment: @AlexisGranja Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado¿? [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/86214/edit) la pregunta

Comment: @AlexisGranja ya lo edite con una simple regex

Comment: Es una solución que también pensé, pero no publiqué, no me convence usar *eval* :P. Podría usarse *String.raw* pero mucha lata.

Comment: Vale aclarar que el string no debería contener `s

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar este snippet, lo que hace es reemplezar los tokens `$id$` por la propiedad `id` en el objeto `contexto`

```js
function analizar(mensaje, contexto)
{
 var tokens = /\$(\w+)\$/g
 return mensaje.replace(tokens, function(token, $1)
 {
  return contexto[$1]  
 })
}

var texto = '¡Hola $var1$! Gracias $var2$'
var contexto = {var1: 'Juan', var2: 'Pedro'}
console.log(analizar(texto, contexto)) // Forma ideal

var var1 = 'María'
var var2 = 'Ana'
console.log(analizar(texto, this)) //No recomendado
```

Comment: hahah Llevo un rato trabajando en la solucion y unos segundos antes la pones... y la misma regex! hahah +1

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Aclararía que el "no recomendado" es únicamente porque se accede al contexto de `window`, pero que podría verificarse, por ejemplo, si es un String para evitar conflictos.